# Index action on production server runs different query from local server

Tags: cakephp

I am developing a Cake 2.4.6 app and the most peculiar thing is happening.

While on my local server (localhost), the index action works and lists my data, my production server generates an SQL "Column not found Error".  Using DebugKit on localhost, I can see the following query:

```
SELECT `Pessoa`.`idpessoa`, `Pessoa`.`idhospital`, `Pessoa`.`nome`, `Pessoa`.`endereco`, `Pessoa`.`status`,
   `Pessoa`.`cat_espiritual`, `Pessoa`.`cat_hierarquica`, `hospital`.`idhospital`, `hospital`.`nome`,
   `hospital`.`endereco` FROM `db`.`pessoas` AS `Pessoa` LEFT JOIN `db`.`hospitals` AS `hospital` ON (`Pessoa`.`idhospital` = `hospital`.`idhospital`) WHERE 1 = 1 LIMIT 20
```

However, the production server is running the following query:

```
SELECT `Pessoa`.`idpessoa`, `Pessoa`.`idhospital`, `Pessoa`.`nome`, `Pessoa`.`endereco`, `Pessoa`.`status`,
   `Pessoa`.`cat_espiritual`, `Pessoa`.`cat_hierarquica`, `hospital`.`idhospital`, `hospital`.`nome`,
   `hospital`.`endereco` FROM `db`.`pessoas` AS `Pessoa` LEFT JOIN `db`.`hospitals` AS `hospital` ON (`Pessoa`.`idhospital` = `hospital`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1 LIMIT 20
```

Note that the JOIN clause uses a different condition (`hospital`.`idhospital` as opposed to `hospital`.ìd`).

How can this happen when production is "git-pulled" from a repo to which localhost commits?

Where should I start looking?  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems I have sorted myself out.

The problem seemed to reside on the Associations I made in the Model files.

My aliases began with "lowercase" as in:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'hospital' => array(
        'className' => 'Hospital',
        'foreignKey' => 'idhospital',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Replacing "hospital" for "Hospital (capital "H") as in:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Hospital' => array(
        'className' => 'Hospital',
        'foreignKey' => 'idhospital',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

... and "pessoa" for "Pessoa" in other associations solved the problem.

It seems that Mac FS is NOT case-sensitive, so this may create issues when developing in Mac and hosting in Linux...